# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; How to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VSCode and have been trying to switch over from Jupyter and am severely struggling. My main project right now is developing a sentiment analysis program for work and I can't even start because I can't read my data in.

This is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data_train = pd.read_csv("trainingData/yelp_review_full_csv/train.csv", header = None)
data_test = pd.read_csv("trainingData/yelp_review_full_csv/test.csv", header = None)
data_train.head(5)
```

My launch.json is

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "python": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have googled every method possible and every time I get the same error. Can someone please advise on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Write the full path of the file. Or put the training data file in the same directory you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

1.When the read file(.py file) and the data file(.csv file) are in the same folder:

1>. When use: `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",` (default value of cwd) in launch.json.

[image]

2>. When use `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"`

[image]

2.When the read file and data file are in different folders: please use `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",`

[image]

Reference: [cwd in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd).